# How to add playing background music in Xcode 6.4 Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, background

I don't know how add background music for my app(game) in Swift. When I'm run it, background music must be played. A few years ago I worked in Xcode, but now it changed, and that's a crap. My app without music. In internet searching I didn't found the answer. Most of all answers connect music playing when you push the button (I don't need it), I need to play music at background when my app is running.

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422014/play-background-music-in-app

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mySound", ofType: "mySound")
let Url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath!)
let mediaPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundFileURL, error: nil)
player.numberOfLoops = -1 //anything less than 0 cause it to unlimited looping
player.play()
```

import AvFoundation !!!!

Comment: AVFoundation added. But where to insert the code in ViewController.swift? In what place paste it that would be without errors?

Comment: That NOT working in xCode 7/ swift 2!!!

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 4.2 Update*** 
**** Make a new class and Paste this code:...........****

```
import AVFoundation

class MusicHelper {
static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper()
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

func playBackgroundMusic() {
let aSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: 
Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MUSICNAME", ofType: "mp3")!) //change the file name as your file
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:aSound as URL)
    audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
    audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer!.play()
}
catch {
    print("Cannot play the file")
}
```

}
.............add this code to view controller................

```
import AVFoundation  **//import at the top**

var player: AVAudioPlayer?  **//declare in code**

MusicHelper.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic() **//paste in viewDidLoad
```

Comment: Please find more ogranized code in here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422014/play-background-music-in-app/54028858#54028858